# Why doesn't Java varargs support collections?

Tags: java, collections, language-features, variadic-functions

In my Java code I often use the very handy `method(Class... args)` varargs. As far as I know, they allow you to pass any amount of `Class` objects or an array of `Class[]`. Since I also often use the Java collection classes, I am frustrated by the lack of compatibility between both. As a result, I end up doing `collection.toArray()`, but that has some type safety issues.

So now for the question: why doesn't Java allow instances of `Iterable<T>` as vararg arguments, as long as the generic type fits the `T...` type of the vararg? Doesn't everyone use lists, sets, etc. all the time? Is there an easy, type-safe way to provide the conversion from collection to vararg?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The reason is simple: a variable arity parameter is simply an old-school array paramater with some additional metadata that tells the compiler to provide some syntactic sugar (namely, it allows implicit array creation).

So from the perspective of the JVM `Object...` is pretty much the same as `Object[]`. Allowing collections as well would require a more invasive change to the JVM (which has no explicit support for collections to date).

Note that if you want to support both ways, then making the collection-based method is probably the better approach:

```
public void frobnicate(Object... args) {
  frobnicate(Arrays.asList(args));
}

public void frobnicate(Iterable<Object> args) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The reason for this is that using `Arrays.asList()` is *usually* a cheaper operation than `Collection.toArray()` (because it creates a simple wrapper).

Comment: It answers the question from a technical point of view, but as a developer, I still think it's silly to supply a helper method whenever I want to use both collections and plain objects. Of course, the fact that we have collections and varargs is already a relief compared to some years ago.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I just prefer using `frobnicate` over a simple `foo`. [source](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/frobnicate.html).

Comment: @tb189: why a "helper method"? You want a method to accept two different, type-wise unrelated kinds of arguments. That's *exactly* the problem that overloading is designed to handle.

Comment: @Jaochim Sauer: Of course, and I agree in case the overloading method actually does something conceptually (e.g. double -> int = rounding, String -> int = parsing with possible errors). In this case, however, as a user of the language (not a technical expert), I feel arrays and collections are the same things functionally, and converting them could be done behind the screens.

Comment: @tb189: and that's where I disagree: they are **not** the same thing. In **my** opinion, arrays are a low-level implementation detail that a normal developer shouldn't care about. *Everything* that is "more than 1 of something" should be a collection. Just because *internally* collections and varargs use arrays doesn't mean that business code should use them as well.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: frobnication is what happens when two paramaters mate.